# i want to scroll the fixed table header with table body data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have multiple columns in my table. I have fixed the table header which is working fine. But when i scrolls the table body columns horizontally..header doesn't move with it. It just fixed. How to solve this issue.

Here's the fiddle
      `<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/waseemak/mpy2ejbm/">Example</a>`

Comment: Headers are scrolling along in the JSFIDDLE.

Comment: Just scroll down to the end and then scroll right..

Comment: have you checked my answer? It will solve your issue.

Comment: check my updated answer and tell me how it goes... I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `position:fixed` css, so if you will remove it, you can see header scrolling along with the all columns.

```
fixed_thead.css({
    //'position': 'fixed',    // I have commented this out
    'top': 0,
    'background-color' : 'white',
    'height': '160px',
    'overflow': 'hidden'
});
```

**The other solution is here:**  `https://jsfiddle.net/5fqLhc37/`

I have added the following snippet to your JS code: and I have attached `class="scroller"` to a div. You can check these changes in jsfiddle.

```
$('.scroller').scroll(function ()
{
    console.log($(this).scrollLeft);
    fixed_thead.offset({ left: -1*this.scrollLeft });
});
```

Comment: but then it does not fix the header

Comment: is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Let me check @waseemak.

Comment: @waseemak, I have updated my answer. Check the JSFIDDLE, it will give you the desired output.

Comment: can i ask another question?

Comment: header is scrolling just like i wanted..but when i scroll horizontally to the end ..table body width doesn't match the header width..columns are not matching at this point

Comment: Here is the solution @waseemak. Check the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5fqLhc37/2/).